# More Flight Routes from India to Grand Cayman

Tags: visas, routes, cayman-islands

Need some more routes from India to Grand Cayman.
How can I book air ticket from India to Georgetown, Cayman Islands without any Transit visa that is required by UK/USA, or which are the countries where I can take connecting flight of same airways or different airways without any further transit visa that is required in USA/UK.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the lists of airlines that serve the Grand Cayman airport on Wikipedia:

[Owen Roberts International Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Roberts_International_Airport)

As you can see most of the connected cities are in US, Canada requires a transit visa for Indian citizens, so your alternative is to travel to Jamaica before (Kingston or Montego Bay)

Jamaica doesn't require a visa for Indian citizen, but Cayman Islands requires a visa for Indian citizens